# Any tips on learning bar chords for guitar-playing?

Tags: guitar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I best learn to play barre chords?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1419/how-can-i-best-learn-to-play-barre-chords)

I am trying to practice songs with bar chords every now and then, but was wondering if anyone had any tips to learn to play bar chords well/comfortably.

Answer (score 1):

Practice, practice, and keep practising!

One thing I used to find was useful is just switching between (say) a D and a Bm chord. Concentrate on getting all the notes to ring out properly and do it slowly and carefully. Then gradually build up speed. You'll find the muscles in your hand will develop and your fingers will begin to find the right positions naturally after a while.