# What does "Trad. G" as a chord mean?

Tags: guitar, chords

Perhaps a beginner question, but I couldn't manage to find the answer online. In the following informal instructions on playing the chords to a guitar song, the author mentions "trad. G":

> Chords Used:
>   Dmaj7, Bm7, Asus6, D/F#, trad. G, F#m7
>
> Finger Pick bass note and B string/ G string
>
> (for the Asus6, play the same notes on the G/B string as Dmaj7)
>
> Chords Played on the A string:
>   Dmaj7, Bm7, F#m7
>
> Chords Played on the E string:
>   G, D/F#, Asus 6

What does he mean by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [several common fingerings of the G chord](https://www.justinguitar.com/en/BC-181-GchordVar-chord.php):

The author is likely referring to the fingering he considers “traditional” (trad.), but without context it’s unclear which specific fingering that means. I suspect it refers to what Justin Guitar calls “Big G” (all strings fretted) although it might refer to “Folk G” instead (A string muted and B string open).

Comment: Cool, happy to help. Out of curiosity, is there something in your source that indicates which specific fingering is correct?

Comment: Not that I can quite tell; it comes from this song, and the playing instructions linked in the description is little more than what I already copied and pasted: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMQdkL-cfGM

Comment: @Feryll  I agree with Bradd and there are several common ways to play a G chord in first or open position (using some open strings).  Click the link below for a chart showing 5 options in first position.  Try them all and see which one works best for the song you want to play. (http://music.stackexchange.com/a/31061/16897)