# Does it matter if the index finger is off the top of the neck playing F barre?

Tags: guitar, chords, beginner

Like pretty much everyone I'm struggling to get good at F barre.  After reading a lot of [these answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1419/best-method-to-learn-to-play-barre-chords) I couldn't find an answer to this:

I've got a pretty good and more and more consistent F recently, with a lot of practice, but the tip of my index finger is almost completely off the top of the neck?  e.g. The 6th string (E) sits only just above the first finger joint and strings 1 (e) and 2 (B) are between the second joint and base of finger.

I seem to be able to play it pretty well - but worry that the index finger is too high?
(ps. Hope I got the strings right!)

[image]

Comment: Post a pic.  That would help

Comment: Please say whether you are playing classical guitar or electric or some other type. I'm guessing classical because you use the term "barre" instead of "bar".   It is important to know however as there are differences in technique (and the width of the neck). P.S. A photo  would be very useful.

Comment: Does you index finger lays flat over 1 st fret?

Comment: @user9339131 - Pretty much flat - it hits all strings but doesn't press the middle ones too hard?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Just a basic acoustic - image added...I normally press a little harder with finger flatter...but trying to take the pic at the same time!

Comment: Not a problem, if hand is comfortable and all strings sounds without buzz then there is no issue. And what's the exact issue?

Comment: @user9339131 Worried that by learning a certain "grip" I'd be heading for trouble further down the line.  Self-teaching (can't afford lessons) so having to make some assumptions.

Comment: No not at all, there is no wrong or right way. I myself is self taught(intermediate/advanced) player and I had major issues with alternate picking(I had to learn it 3 times, seriously), holding guitar(I kept my thumb always over fretboard which contributed in slow progress), and still struggling with my right hand technique(but I am getting better). It is no doubt that it's difficult to be self taught but doing mistake is part of learning. If you are doing something wrong, it will be hurdle in learning and you have to correct it and that is fun(seriously). Hope it motivates you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything wrong with the tip of the index finger sticking out off the neck when playing barre. Similarly you may find that in some cases when you're supposed to play barre over e.g. two or three strings it is easier to put the finger over more strings. It may depend on specific chord shape as well as on your individual anatomical shape of hand and fingers.

What matters is that the notes sound clear and without the buzz (and also that notes that are not supposed to sound, don't), that you avoid excessive muscle tension and you have freedom in placing the other fingers where they should be and that it doesn't prevent you from switching the chords smoothly.

Comment: Thank you - I'll stick with it as its coming out clear.

Comment: "that you avoid excessive muscle tension" this is so important I thought I'd quote it :)

Comment: @Thomas right. Actually, the more the finger is "sticking out" the closer is the part that is touching the strings to the joint that connects finger with the palm. This reduces the moment of force (which translates into your effort or muscle tension) needed to apply necessary force on the strings.

Answer (score 4):

Since there is such a discrepancy in the length of fingers between players - and the ratio of finger lengths for individuals - it matters not *how* much finger covers certain strings. As long as those stringss can be successfully pressed and sound, and other strings can also sound.

Also a large consideration must be the comfort afforded by your positioning. If it hurts, it's not good in the long term. There's also the fact that the majority of guitar players press way too hard, especially when barring chords like this.

Another option, frowned upon by classical guitarists, is to use the thumb over the top to fret that bottom string. With longer thumbs, it can be successful.

It may be worth experimenting to see if your shape hinders *changing* chords. Sometimes one particular shape makes moving from another shape to that, or that to another shape, not as fluid as it could be.

But if all is well, keep going at it. There cannot be the 'same 'ideal' way for all of us.

Comment: There is a gender aspect that comes into play here as well.  It's not 100% of course, but statistically speaking, women's hands tend to have the index finger longer than the ring finger, while on men's hands it's shorter.  (Middle finger is longer than both regardless.)  This can directly affect how much finger is used in a barre chord.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Note that length of the finger is not the only factor, but also location and shape of the joints. It's sometimes difficult to press the string properly if it's just under the joint.